# not able to export Crystal report file to pdf

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports

I have application in .net ,I created Crystal report from my application.
after creating crystal report i tryied to export that crystal file to PDF..
but i am getting error like this

Error in file

[image]

As per my search result i have Installed 2 dll files  `exportmodeller.dll, crtslv.dll` and i re-installed update version of adobe reader(11.0.13),but still getting this error? thanks in advance

Comment: It is possible that you are using a font that is not accepted. Are you using a barcode font in this report?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Microsoft update (KB3102429), which causes this issue. Here is an article how to remove it: http://www.iris.co.uk/support/knowledgebase/kb/11478

Answer (score 0):

The last Microsoft update (KB3102429) causes this error.

More information about this problem you can find on support: https://scn.sap.com/thread/3828300

Solution: removed that update (KB3102429)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I found the description of the problem in :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102429

The solution of the problem can be found at:

https://blog.brankovucinec.com/2015/12/10/kb3102429-causes-crystal-report-export-to-pdf-to-fail/

Notes:

This problem occurs when you use a DataSet as a source of report data. Sql queries and StoredProcedures this error did not happen
This problem occurs when you will export the report to PDF using a DataSet as a data source, if you try to export to Excell and Word this does not happen.
You must remove this update from your computer or server (if this problem).

1: Go to Control Panel

2: Select View installed updates

3: Search the KB3102429 update, And Then select Uninstall.
If you can not uninstall this update:

Issue only manifests with export to PDF using DataSet (Word and Excell not affected), only if the report contains TNR or Arial (no other fonts found to cause a problem but not every font was tested) and only with the versions of fonts, if you change the fonts on your report to SergoeUI your report (maybe) will work.