# Crystal Reports 10 app no longer exporting to PDF

Tags: delphi, pdf, crystal-reports

I maintain an app that uses Crystal Reports 10 for report generation. Exporting reports to PDF is a common task. Exporting to PDF just stopped working. In fact on my machine I can't even export to PDF from the Designer anymore.

I suspect a recent upgrade by Adobe Reader to v11.0.10 was the culprit; I haven't been able to export since. I manually updated the AR to 11.0.13 - the latest I can find - but this has not helped.

A re-install both of the app and/or CR10 has not helped.

Odd thing is on the same machine I have another app that uses CR8.5 for reporting and exporting to PDF from that app is not a problem.

Both apps are written in Delphi if that helps.

Comment: Which AR version was installed before the upgrade to 11.0.10, a 11.x or a 10.x version?

Comment: I don't know. Its not something I pay much attention to. I do always make sure Reader has to notify me rather than allow automatic updates. I've tried figuring out which version the old one was but without any luck.

Comment: Problem solved - it's MS' fault: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186178/not-able-to-export-crystal-report-file-to-pdf

Comment: If you can't even export from the Crystal Report designer, the question has no relation to Delphi